# ¿Cómo pasar un campo con información que me devuelva un formulario con los datos de todos los campos en php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, update

para poneros en situación, yo tengo un formulario donde he recogido un array de un campo de mi tabla:

En la imagen se puede ver que tengo el campo número donde recoge todos los teléfonos de unos clientes, lo que yo quiero es que gracias a poner uno de estos números, me pase a otro formulario con toda la información puesta de ese cliente, ese formulario es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El otro formulario se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pongo el código para ver si puede ayudar, yo creo que debería de salirme ya toda la información porque he creado un nuevo select * con un where, pero no funciona.

PHP Formulario 1:

```
<?php
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jardineria");
 $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM clientes");

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Ejemplo
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="jardineria7.php" method="GET">
            <div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid #FCC; padding: 10px;">
                <center>
                    <h2>Telefonos de los clientes de la base jardineria</h2>
                    <select>
                        <?php
                        while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                        ?>
                             <option value=""> <?php echo $datos['Telefono'] ?> </option>
                        <?php
                        }    
                        ?>
                            <input type="submit">
                         <?php
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]
```

PHP FORMULARIO 2 (información clientes)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="es-ES"> 
<head> 
      <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
      <title>Insertar clientes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilosimple.css"/>
</head> 
<body>
<?php
//Establecer conexión
$c=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","")
    or die ("No se puede conectar");
//Seleccionar la base de datos
mysqli_select_db ($c,"jardineria")
    or die ("No es posible acceder a la base de datos");
if (isset($_REQUEST['enviar'])){
//coger valores del formulario
//Más rápido con extract
/*$NombreCliente = $_REQUEST['NombreCliente'];
$NombreContacto = $_REQUEST['NombreContacto'];
$ApellidoContacto = $_REQUEST['ApellidoContacto'];
$Telefono = $_REQUEST['Telefono'];
$Fax = $_REQUEST['Fax'];
$LineaDireccion1 = $_REQUEST['LineaDireccion1'];
$LineaDireccion2 = $_REQUEST['LineaDireccion2'];
$Ciudad = $_REQUEST['Ciudad'];
$Region = $_REQUEST['Region'];
$Pais = $_REQUEST['Pais'];
$CodigoPostal = $_REQUEST['CodigoPostal'];
$CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas = $_REQUEST['CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas'];
$LimiteCredito = $_REQUEST['LimiteCredito'];*/
extract($_REQUEST);
    $consulta = "select NombreCliente, NombreContacto FROM clientes";
    $Telefono=trim($_GET['valor']);
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Telefono='$Telefono'") or die (mysqli_error());
    $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo "".$row['NombreCliente']."";
echo "".$row['NombreContacto']."";
echo "".$row['ApellidoContacto']."";

    $rescon2 = mysqli_query ($c,$consulta);
    $valor = mysqli_fetch_row ($rescon2);
    //Se averigua cuál es el código máximo de empleado existente.
        $insercion = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES('$NombreCliente','$NombreContacto', '$ApellidoContacto', $Telefono, $Fax, '$LineaDireccion1', '$LineaDireccion2', '$Ciudad', '$Region', '$Pais', '$CodigoPostal', $CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas, $LimiteCredito)";
        echo "Sentencia de inserción:$insercion<br/>";
        if(mysqli_query($c,$insercion))
            echo "Inserción completada correctamente<br/>";
        else 
            echo "Ha ocurrido error al ejecutar sentencia SQL INSERT<br/>";       
}
else{?>
<form  action='#' method='get'>


     <h2>Rellene los datos del cliente</h2>
     <table border="1">
     <tr>
    <td>Nombre del cliente</td><td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $querypp['NombreCliente']; ?>" required="required" name="NombreCliente" size="50" maxlength="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Nombre del contacto</td><td><input type="text" name="NombreContacto" maxlength="30" size="30"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Apellido del contacto</td><td><input type="text" name="ApellidoContacto" maxlength="30"  size="30"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Teléfono</td><td><input type="text" required="required" name="Telefono"   size="11" maxlength="11" pattern="[0-9]{9,11}">  
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Fax </td><td><input type="text" name="Fax" required="required" maxlength="11"  size="11" pattern="[0-9]{9,11}"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Dirección 1</td><td><input type="text" required="required" name="LineaDireccion1"  size="50" maxlength="50"/></td> 
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Dirección 2</td><td><input type="text" name="LineaDireccion2" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td> 
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Ciudad</td><td><input type="text" required="required"  name="Ciudad" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Región</td><td><input type="text" name="Region" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>    
    <td>País</td><td><input type="text" name="Pais" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Código Postal</td><td><input type="text"  name="CodigoPostal" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{5}" size="5" ></td>
    </tr><tr>   
    <td>Límite Crédito</td>
    <td><input type="number" required="required" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="10000" name="LimiteCredito"  size="20"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Código empleado</td>
    <td>
    <?php   

    echo "<select name = 'CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas'>";
            $consulta = "SELECT CodigoEmpleado, Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2 FROM empleados";
            $rescon = mysqli_query ($c,$consulta);
            while($valor = mysqli_fetch_row ($rescon)){ 
                echo "<option value = $valor[0]>".$valor[0]." </option>";
            } 
    mysqli_close ($c);
    echo "</select>";
     ?>
     </td> </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
    </body>
</html>
<?php }?>
```

Gracias, espero que podáis ayudarme.

Answer (score 2):

para empezar, en formulario 1 te falto name al `<select>` (en mi caso puse `name="telefono"`) para el caso practico que aplique yo, creo que esto te puede ayudar.

```
<?php 
        // obtengo el nro de telefono de formulario 1       
        if(isset($_POST['telefono']))
        {
            $tel = strval($_POST['telefono']);
            $mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jardineria");
            $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM clientes where Telefono = '$tel';");

             while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
             {
                $datos_cliente['nombre'] = $datos['NombreCliente'];
                $datos_cliente['nombre_contacto'] = $datos['NombreContacto'];
                $datos_cliente['apellido_contacto'] = $datos['ApellidoContacto'];
             }       

?>
<form  action='#' method='get'>


     <h2>Rellene los datos del cliente</h2>
     <table border="1">
     <tr>
    <td>Nombre del cliente</td><td><input type="text" value="<?=$datos_cliente['NombreCliente']; ?>" required="required" name="NombreCliente" size="50" maxlength="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Nombre del contacto</td><td><input type="text" name="NombreContacto" value="<?=$datos_cliente['nombre_contacto']; ?>"  maxlength="30" size="30"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Apellido del contacto</td><td><input type="text" name="ApellidoContacto"  value="<?=$datos_cliente['apellido_contacto']; ?>" maxlength="30"  size="30"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Teléfono</td><td><input type="text" required="required" name="Telefono"   size="11" maxlength="11" pattern="[0-9]{9,11}">  
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Fax </td><td><input type="text" name="Fax" required="required" maxlength="11"  size="11" pattern="[0-9]{9,11}"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Dirección 1</td><td><input type="text" required="required" name="LineaDireccion1"  size="50" maxlength="50"/></td> 
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Dirección 2</td><td><input type="text" name="LineaDireccion2" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td> 
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Ciudad</td><td><input type="text" required="required"  name="Ciudad" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Región</td><td><input type="text" name="Region" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>    
    <td>País</td><td><input type="text" name="Pais" maxlength="50"  size="50"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Código Postal</td><td><input type="text"  name="CodigoPostal" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{5}" size="5" ></td>
    </tr><tr>   
    <td>Límite Crédito</td>
    <td><input type="number" required="required" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="10000" name="LimiteCredito"  size="20"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Código empleado</td>
    <td>
    <?php   

    echo "<select name = 'CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas'>";
            $consulta = "SELECT CodigoEmpleado, Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2 FROM empleados";
            $rescon = mysqli_query ($c,$consulta);
            while($valor = mysqli_fetch_row ($rescon)){ 
                echo "<option value = $valor[0]>".$valor[0]." </option>";
            } 
    mysqli_close ($c);
    echo "</select>";
     ?>
     </td> </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
    </body>
</html>
<?php }?>







        }




 ?>
```

Comment: Creo que he añadido todo bien según mi información, pero sigue sacándome la variable no definida.

Answer (score 1):

Te añadiría un comentario, pero no puedo comentar todavía, así que te respondo directamente:

El error que te está dando es porque la variable o no está siendo bien enviada (Lo cual creo que está bien), o bien no estás construyendo bien la sentencia `sql` con las variables en `php`, me explico:

```
$insercion = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES('$NombreCliente','$NombreContacto', '$ApellidoContacto', $Telefono, $Fax, '$LineaDireccion1', '$LineaDireccion2', '$Ciudad', '$Region', '$Pais', '$CodigoPostal', $CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas, $LimiteCredito)";
```

Esto de aquí no es válido, tienes que concatenar las variables correctamente, de la siquiente manera:

```
$insercion = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES('\".$NombreCliente."\','\".$NombreContacto"\', '\".$ApellidoContacto."\', '\".$Telefono."\', '\".$Fax."\', '$LineaDireccion1."\', '\".$LineaDireccion2."\', '\".$Ciudad"\', '$Region"\', '\".$Pais."\', '\".$CodigoPostal."\', '\".$CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas."\', '\".$LimiteCredito."\')";
```

PD: Te recomiendo usar un `framework`, como `PDO`, para que se entiendan `sql` y `php` de manera más sencilla.

2º PD: Es posible que alguna concatenación que haya puesto no sea correcta, ya que es un jaleo el escapar comillas.

Comment: ¿Debería de ir entre un <?php ?> ? Es que he estado probando y no entiende la línea, ya que de ahí en adelante me sale todo como campo texto.

Comment: Todo código que sea php, tiene que ir entre las etiquetas de php si, pero ese código ya está dentro de la etiqueta. Seguramente alguna concatenación no sea correcta, y por eso te da error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te entendi bien, creo que tienes que hacer algo así:

en el select, ponerle esto:

```
onchange="this.form.submit()
```

Lo que va a hacer es que después de seleccionar una opción el formulario, este se va a enviar hacia la URL del action(que lo tienes como #), en este caso la etiqueta form debe ser así:

```
<form  action="" method="GET">
```

Digamos que elegi el numero: 555393932, entonces te va a enviar a la siguiente URL:

> ejer/jardineria7.php?telefono=555393932

entonces ya estamos obteniendo el teléfono con un GET,
ahora solo falta hacer uso de esa variable en tu consulta, asignamos el GET a una variable, y eliminamos etiquetas y/o codificamos los caracteres especiales de la variable con filter_var():

```
$telefono = filter_var($_GET['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Después la utilizas en tu consulta:

```
 $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Telefono='$telefono'");
```

El formulario debe quedar algo asi:

```
<form  action="" method="GET">
<select name="telefono" onchange="this.form.submit()" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Selecciona un teléfono </option>
    <option value="555393932"> 555393932 </option>
    <option value="555372000"> 555372000 </option>
    <option value="555928020"> 555928020 </option>
</select>
</form>
```

Ahora toca validar unas cosas

Primero, verificar que estemos recibiendo el GET con un valor o de lo contrario mostrará la tabla del cliente con los errores de de **Udefined variable**

```
if(!isset($_GET['telefono']) or $_GET['telefono'] == ''){
   //Si no existe el GET o el GET está vacio. 
   //Aqui ponemos el select de los teléfonos
   echo "<h1>Selecciona un teléfono para mostrar...</h1>";
}else{
   //Como ya seleccionó un teléfono, entonces ponemos el código de las
   //ponemos también el formulario, la tabl, la consulta etc...
}
```

Y por ultimo te recomiendo siempre usar minúsculas en tus variables.

Comment: Lo he probado, pero nada, el segundo select de teléfonos debería de recoger el anterior valor únicamente dicho en el anterior formulario, gracias por tu interés.